# High quality instrumental backing tracks for vocal demo recording

Tags: recording, vocals

I'm looking to branch out into recording professional vocal demos for singers.

I'm going to need to access a catalogue of professional commercial backing tracks (that the singer can choose from). Sam Smith and Adele would be a good start, if you'd like an example of the kind of music they'll want.

Ideally the format of the track would be Stereo 44.1KHz and 24bit, however 16bit would be OK. Would be best if I can just purchase per track and download. It probably won't be frequent enough to be worth a monthly subscription service.

Does anyone have experience of using such a service that they can recommend?

Comment: What about karaoke CDs?

Comment: Are you looking for tracks for new songs, or for existing songs?

Comment: Hi @Linuxios I'm looking for existing famous songs, like Adele and Sam Smith etc.

Comment: Hi @ToddWilcox I think I must have a pre-concieved idea that Karaoke CD's are poor quality, maybe that's a hang-over from the late 90's when I used to avoid them like the plague!

Comment: Actually thinking about this, do any Karaoke CD's use the original recording stems, just without lead vocals? @ToddWilcox

Comment: The only Karaoke I'm aware of that uses the original tracks is the series released by Motown. Everything else is a cover - quality varies. I wouldn't be certain about the legality of using either type to record your own vocals over, though - best to ask the karaoke company, or check their licensing terms carefully.

Comment: Nowadays, Japan usually includes instrumental/karaoke version in their singles/album having as high/same quality as the vocal version (I can assure on this, because I usually prefer the instrumental ver. than the vocal one). However, I'm not sure if it applies in other countries. Also, I agree with Tetsujin that you should ask the artist for permission first.

Comment: I'm going to record the song as a professional demo, it turns out there was an instrumental version of the song the singer has chosen. Luckily I can download a HQ version online! I'm not looking to release or publish it, I'm just looking to work with singers and working on a demo is a good start to finding out if they're up to the job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karaoke CDs would be okay. There are a few services that offer stems for remixing like https://www.beatport.com/stems. However, it might be hard to find the style you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for contributing John. I wonder if anyone has an opinion on really well recorded Karaoke CD's or are they all of a similar quality? (Hopefully not like the old tacky MIDI versions haha)

Comment: You can find non-MIDI versions, but there is the question of legality. I guess the question is how much will they be distributed etc... It's really a grey area with format shifting and especially if you aren't directly profiting on them. If you have consent from the makers of the backing track it might be worth it. However, the best solution is to use some original tracks. I would check out producers and songwriters who are also trying to get some exposure and demo stuff -- if you work together it will be much more impressive than simple backing tracks. (And free.)